# calling of dataInit and dataEvents after the control are placed on the page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jquery autocomplete and jquery chosen in my grid add pop up.
I want chosen(adrs column) values to be populated on the basis of autocomplete(user column) selection i.e. ajax should take autocomplete selection to backend and get the results for chosen.
For this I want chosen dataInit to be called after populating autocomplete.

How can I do this because dataInit is called as soon as pop up opens.

steps that I am following

1. populate user autocomplete when the user starts typing into it.
2. till this time the adrs chosen is already avilable on the DOM.

Expected Behaviour : 
1.Select user from user autocomplete drop down
2. send the selected user value in ajax call that will help in populating the chosen dropdown.

Problem :

1. How to use selected user in ajax call for adrs chosen .
2. I want chosen results to be populated/refreshed after selecting user.I am using dataInit for this ,not sure if I have to use any other dataEvents.

Thanks..

```
    {name:"user",index:"user",editoptions:{
     dataInit: function (elem) {
                             setTimeout(function(){   

                            var dataSrc= function(request, response,term) {  
                                        $.ajax({
                                            //this will populate autocomplete
                                    };
                                   $(elem).autocomplete({
                                       source: dataSrc,
                                       minLength: 3
                                   });
                             },50);
                     }
}
},
{name:"adrs",index:"adrs",edittype:'select','editoptions': {
                    dataInit: function (elem) {


                            var optionBlank = document.createElement('option');
                            optionBlank.text = "esefasd1" ;
                            optionBlank.value = "ds1fas" ;
                            elem.add(optionBlank);
                                                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                            option.text = "esefasd" ;
                            option.value = "dsfas" ;
                            elem.add(option);


                        $(elem).chosen();
                     }//END Dataint

                    }}
```

I want to fire an ajax for adrs column as well which will take selected user as input.As of now this chosen is getting populated with pop up only. I want to populate it after selecting user.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by wrapping of the call of `autocomplete` in `setTimeout`:

```js
dataInit: function (elem) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(elem).autocomplete({...});
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg for quick reply. This will delay autocomplete, but how can I use value selected in autocomplete text box for chosen ? and how can I delay chosen datainit call to happen after selecting from autocomplete and not on openeing pop up. I have added code for reference.

Comment: @user2640846: Sorry, but I can't follow you. I suppose that you use some wrong **options of jQuery UI Autocomplete**. Autocomplete will be not opened till the text (3 chars in your case). If required you can use `select` callback of autocomplete, but I never used it during editing, only in searching dialog. Why you not just use URL which provides the data as the value of `source`? In any way I still don't understand from your last comment which problem exactly you have with autocomplete.

Comment: @user2640846: What is work not fine? I reread multiple times the description from your previous comment and don't understand what problem you have currently. Could you explain the problem in other words. Some statements like "I want chosen dataInit to be called after populating autocomplete" are absolutely wrong. jqGrid have callbacks which allows you to do some actions at specific moment. `dataInit` will be called duing initialization of editing input.  You can't say I want that specific callback will be called at another moment. It's like to ask success callback to call not on success.

Comment: autocomplete is working fine.I have to use jquery chosen(harvesthq.github.io/chosen) plugin for adrs column which should be populated after selecting from user(autocomplete) column.editype for 2nd column is "select"

Comment: updated my question. "dataInit will be called duing initialization of editing input". what should I use if I want to delay the call ?

Comment: @user2640846: It's wrong question. You can delay the call of `autocomplete` inside of your implementation of `dataInit` callback, but not on the contrary. It's like you can't change the date of birth of your mother. You can only change the time when your children will be born.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Oleg for the support.
I solved by calling a method from user dataEvents(type:'blur') to populate adrs chosen and called "chosen:updated" in this method.